# Manage PostgreSQL client backend

Tags: postgresql, configuration

To get currently runnig processes, I run these queries :

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

---

I have some questions about outputs:

1. What is `client backend`? Why there are a lot of `client backend`?  What does it mean?
2. How to manage `client backend` and how to config it? Is it ok to have so many `client backend`? How much resources we need for each `client backend`?

Comment: Please post text as text, not nearly invisible images (dark green on black?) nor even high contrast images for that matter.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One `client backend` line for each client connection. Start `psql` - you will get a new `client backend`, an open database connection from the application - a new `client backend`, an application with a pool of up to 30 concurrent DB connections - up to 30 `client backend` processes. In postgresql, every connection from any client is forked as a new process.

The maximum number of connections is the `max_connections` setting, not `max_worker_processes`.

Each client connection process keeps its own cache of the system catalog, stored procedures, its own RAM segment for temporary table data, can store an indefinite number of prepared statements, cursors, and so on. Dozens and hundreds of megabytes of memory for each process is not very difficult to obtain. 10 busy processes is much more efficient than 300 opened connections, but occasionally executing queries. That's why pgbouncer (in transaction pool mode) is usually running between the application and postgresql in production.